# Order of modifiers and return type in method declaration

Tags: java

Why do I get a compile time error when I declare a method as `public void static subMethod()` instead of `public static void subMethod()`?

```
class Example{
    public void static subMethod() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        subMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because [that's not the correct syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4). Modifiers go before the return type. There's not much more to say about it.

Answer (score 5):

Because the spec says so.

Specifically, the ordering goes:

```
modifiers returntype methodname(ArgType1 argName1, ArgType2 argName2, ...) { ... }
```

Where `modifiers` can be placed in any order you want. For example `static public void subMethod() {}` is just as legal, but note that just like in english it sounds weird to say "A green little book" and correct to say "A little green book", `public static` sounds right and `static public` sounds wrong.

`void` takes the place of return type and therefore CANNOT be part of the modifiers, it most come after them (or rather, modifiers cannot come after `void`).

Don't write `String args[]`. Legal, but, not idiomatic at all. Write `String[] args` instead.

Answer (score 0):

because the **modifier** goes behind the **returntype** . the correct order is public static void . and also there is a useless **`** after the opening **{** in your main method . also there is a } missing . their number should be even . also when you want to use a static method there's no need to create an object of the class but use the class name before the method, like this : **Example.submethod();**